# vue multiselect 1.1.4, select value by id

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i added multiselect component which looks like this

**View**

```
<multiselect
  :options="books"
  :selected="selectedBook"
  :show-labels="false"
  placeholder="Choose your book"
  label="name">
  <span slot="noResult">No books were found</span>
</multiselect>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        books: [],
        selectedBook: null,
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getBooks();
      this.getFav();
    },
    methods: {
      getBooks() {
        this.$http
        .get('/books/')
        .then(
          function(response) {
            this.books = response.json();
          }
        );
      },
      getFav() {
        this.$http
        .get('/fav/')
        .then(
          function(response) {
            var fav = response.json();
            this.selectedBook = fav.id;
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Response**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"ABC"},{"id":2,"name":"QWE"}]
```

And my question is, how can i set selected book by id. when i set like this, then in input shows id, but i want the book name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `track-by`

```
<multiselect
  ...
  track-by="id"
  label="name"
  ...
>
```

ref: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-single-select-object

Comment: Hi, my `options` also getting from api, but after putting in `track-by="id"`, it shows the following error: `Property or method "id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property`