# Component vue-multiselect- doesn't fetch value on load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-multiselect

When loading a component, I need to select the value in the drop-down list

I'm trying to make my code friends with vue-multiselect

found a similar topic - however, nothing appears in the field - if you then select a value, everything works correctly [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562404/vue-multiselect-1-1-4-select-value-by-id)

in fact, I have to download via axios, the mini version looks like this

```
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";

export default {  
components: {
  Multiselect
},
data() {
  return {
    books: [],
    selectedBook: null,
    };
  },
created() {
  this.getBooks();
  this.getFav();
},
methods: {
//through axios I get the model and pass it to the list component
  getBooks() {
    this.books = [
      { id: 1, name: "ABC" },
      { id: 2, name: "QWE" }
    ];
},
getFav() {
//through axios I get the Id of the model for editing
  let responseId = 1;
  this.selectedBook = responseId;
},


<template>
 ...
 <multiselect
   v-model="selectedBook"
   :options="books"
   :selected="selectedBook"
   track-by="id"
   label="name"
   :show-labels="false"
   placeholder="Choose your book">
     <span slot="noResult">No books were found</span>
 </multiselect>
 <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ selectedBook }}</code></pre>
 ...
 </template>
```

but when the form is loaded and opened - there is nothing in the select box,

and if you make a choice from the list, then the model changes

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/XF0nY9X)

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/cro48jm0/2/)

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget just one line of code: in your multiselect tag add `v-model="selectedBook"`, like

```
<multiselect
 :options="books"
 :selected="selectedBook"
 :show-labels="false"
 track-by="id"
 label="name"
 placeholder="Choose your book"
 v-model="selectedBook" 
>
```

And if you want a book to be already selected when you load the component (so a default book, for example the first one). You have to modify your getFav() function, which is called when creating the component:

```
  getFav() {
    var fav = 1; /*id of the book to display*/
    var defaultIndex = this.books.findIndex(x => x.id === fav);
    this.selectedBook = this.books[defaultIndex];
  }
```

Comment: v-model available in code, and I need to display the selected one when loading the component, I do not need to select multiple books

Comment: So you want that a default book is pre selected by the loading of the component and that under it you see the id and name too ?

Comment: this is what I want to achieve, 
the usual form when editing - the drop-down list must be filled

Comment: this is a little different - because in the getFav () response, an indicator may come with not 1 - but some other - for example: 29, how then to search the array for the line number where Id = 29?

Comment: So if I understood correctly your multiselect component is the child of a parent. The parent sends an event to multiselect with the book id, which should be the default book. And multiselect will display the book with the id received from the parent as preselected when it loads.

Comment: Yes, this is an editing form, and when I open it, I load an object that has an identifier from the drop-down list - and of course, what was selected when creating the object should be displayed  {id = "1", selectedbook="29", name="Mymy", Firstname="KEKE" and order props)

Comment: Ok I just didn't understand how you get the book id to post from the parent. So I assumed it's the fav variable.

Comment: Then to go further, I also noticed that your child (multiselect) does not listen on an event. However, if you want to react to an id (1, 29 or whatever you want) that you send from the parent, multiselect must listen on this event and then you just have to write `var fav = this.theIdFromParent`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in comments, you may pass the object itself to `this.selectedBook`. I suggest you to write your `getFav` function like this:

```js
getFav() {
  let responseId = 2; // get the id from axios, for example 2
  let displayedItem = null;
  // map the books array to find the corresponding item id
  this.books.map(item => {
    if(item.id === responseId) {
      this.displayedItem = item;
    };
  });
  this.selectedBook = this.displayedItem;
}
```